# Load json data via url on button click - Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get JSON data from `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=type%3Auser` as input in text box via button click like below

Here's my code from the template:

```
<input value="" [(ngModel)]="url"> 
<button (click)="getData()" type="button" name="button">Test</button>
```

And in the Component Class:

```
getData(): void {
  console.log(this.name);
}
```

but I'm getting the same URL in the log.

I know basically, we will be using service where we configure `url` and `httpClient` module then call that service method in the target component. Like

```
sample service
--------------
getAllUser(){
  return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/search/users?q=type%3Auser');
}

dummy component
---------------
this.dummyService.getAllUser(){
  // doing whatever i want
}
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4q98ag?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

But I want call the URL as I mentioned above?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Try to make a stackblitz example, and for your problem you might want to to use something like `this.dummyService.getAllUsers(HERE_YOU_PUT_THE_URL_FROM_THE_COMPONENT).subscribe(console.log)`

Comment: Hi @noririco i've added stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a77dm4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can just hit the API via `HttpClient`'s `get`method to get the API response and then unwrap the `Observable` holding the response in the template using the `async` pipe.

Updated your code sample for a minimal implementation for for simplicity's sake.

Try this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = '';
  users$;

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}

  test(): void {
    console.log(this.name);
    this.users$ = this.http
      .get(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${this.name}`)
      .pipe(map((res: any) => res.items));
  }
}
```

And in your Component Template:

```
<input value="" placeholder="use below url" [(ngModel)]="name">

<button (click)="test()" type="button" name="button">Test</button>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of (users$ | async)">
    <pre> {{ user | json }}</pre>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE:**

To get the complete URL From the User and then hitting that URL To get the data, you could just do this:

```
apiResponse$: Observable<any>;

test(): void {
  console.log(this.name);
  this.apiResponse$ = this.http
    .get(this.name);
}
```

> Here's the **[Working Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-github-user-search-sample?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** for your ref.

Comment: Hi @SiddAjmera i've already tried like your demo in my local which was working fine.. what I'm actually trying is instead of giving  `SiddAjmera `as input i want give the whole url itself and to get response

Comment: i just modified like this ` .get(this.name)` and its working me ... so here the ngModal and passing the ngModal value in GET method as params is the matter.. finally its working for me